# SceneKit – How to show SCN file in the scene view?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want to show a 3D object in my application so I used SceneKit to do so. As I never used this module before I was facing two issues to show the object:

- When I entered the name of `scn` file in sceneView at the storyboard it shows as it is and I can't make any interactions on it.
- When I use class of SCNScene to type the name as below it shows nothing and ended up with a thread found nil.

Here's a code:

```
private func setupScene() {

   let url = Bundle(for: CarModelVC.self).url(forResource: "art.scnassets/veh", 
                                            withExtension: "scn")
   scnScene = SCNSceneSource(url: url!)?.scene()
   self.scene = scnScene
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to get what you want:

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func setupScene() -> SCNScene? {   

        guard let url = Bundle(for: CarModelVC.self).url(forResource: "art.scnassets/veh",
                                                       withExtension: "scn")
        else { return nil }

        let scnScene = SCNSceneSource(url: url)?.scene()       
        return scnScene!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView

        sceneView.scene = self.setupScene()
    }
}
```